# How to use prepareSegue method in storyboard?

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       ThirdViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        segue.destinationViewController displayTitlesArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"first ",@"second",@"Third", nil ];}
```

display titles array is array in next view controller.But here I'm getting error.How can i pass the data to next view controller using segue.destinationViewController object.

Comment: can i know why it is down voted?

Comment: Maybe because you can find tons of examples or tutorials searching on Google: http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=How%20to%20use%20prepareSegue%20method%20in%20storyboard%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=XsFtVKrCK-aq8weKxoHQBg

Comment: I did not downvote but you ask hundred times answered question, thats why.

Comment: edited the question.Please check the code

Comment: What kind of error did you get?

Comment: @Pvni, if you want a code review, use the appropriate site - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. I mean no offense, but Stack Overflow is not a place for making code reviews, nor a place to ask questions of type "fix my code", it is about finding solutions to more-conceptual problems, or ones that require deep technical knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       ThirdViewController *destViewController = (ThirdViewController  *)segue.destinationViewController;
       destViewController.displayTitlesArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"first ",@"second",@"Third", nil ];}
```